# Após @JoinColumn JPA nao encontra atributo do entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, atributos

Eu tenho duas entidades que estão diretamente relacionadas @Entity **Estado** e @Entity **Cidade** e meu intuito era renomear a chave estrangeira presente na entitidade cliente, alterando por exemplo, de 'cidade.estado_idEstado' para 'cidade.idEstado'. Para isto utilizei a annotation @JoinColumn ,entretanto, parece que após esta alteração o Hibernate procura um atributo com o nome que atribui à propriedade NAME da annotation em questão, porém, na entidade Estado eu ja especifiquei o atributo 'estado' como valor do mappedBy.

@Entity **Estado**

```
@Entity
public class Estado {

    @Id
    private int idEstado;
    @Column(length=2)
    private String sigla;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="estado",targetEntity=Cidade.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Cidade> cidades;
    public int getIdEstado() {
        return idEstado;
    }
    public void setIdEstado(int idEstado) {
        this.idEstado = idEstado;
    }
    public String getSigla() {
        return sigla;
    }
    public void setSigla(String sigla) {
        this.sigla = sigla;
    }
    public List<Cidade> getCidades() {
        return cidades;
    }
    public void setCidades(List<Cidade> cidades) {
        this.cidades = cidades;
    }
}
```

@Entity **Cidade**

```
@Entity
public class Cidade {
    @Id 
    private int idCidade;
    @Column(length=30)
    private String nomeCidade;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idEstado")
    private Estado estado;
    public int getIdCidade() {
        return idCidade;
    }
    public void setIdCidade(int idCidade) {
        this.idCidade = idCidade;
    }
    public String getNomeCidade() {
        return nomeCidade;
    }
    public void setNomeCidade(String nomeCidade) {
        this.nomeCidade = nomeCidade;
    }
    public Estado getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }
    public void setEstado(Estado estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }
    public Estado getIdEstado() {
        return estado;
    }
    public void setIdEstado(Estado estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }   
}
```

**Consulta**

```
TypedQuery<Cidade> queryCidades = em.createQuery("select c from Cidade c where c.estado =:codigoEstado",Cidade.class);
queryCidades.setParameter("codigoEstado", 1);
List<Cidade> cidades = queryCidades.getResultList();
```

**Erro**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private int br.com.biblioteca.model.Estado.idEstado] by reflection for persistent property [br.com.biblioteca.model.Estado#idEstado] : 1
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1407)
    at org.hibernate.Query.getResultList(Query.java:427)
    at br.com.biblioteca.model.Principal.main(Principal.java:26)
Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private int br.com.biblioteca.model.Estado.idEstado] by reflection for persistent property [br.com.biblioteca.model.Estado#idEstado] : 1
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4662)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4373)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:628)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1956)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:932)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1426)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1398)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field br.com.biblioteca.model.Estado.idEstado to java.lang.Integer
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.getInt(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getInt(Field.java:574)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:58)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: Posso propor testar usando Integer nos atributos idEstado e idCidade? Não como resposta mesmo, mas teste. É disso que o stack trace reclama como erro raiz

Comment: irei tentar assim que chegar em casa.

Comment: Deu certo! Coloque como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chamou-me a atenção a causa raíz dos problemas:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field br.com.biblioteca.model.Estado.idEstado to java.lang.Integer
```

Sugeri então trocar os campos declarados como `primitivo int` para `Integer`, na esperança do framework não se perder. No caso, os atributos `idEstado` e `idCidade`.

O resultado final foi positivo, tendo resolvido a questão atual.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, você está utilizando a query do TypedQuery, o esperado neste cenário de passagem de parâmetro é você utilizar o próprio objeto estado da cidade, que o hibernate irá se resolver. Ficando:

```
TypedQuery<Cidade> queryCidades = em.createQuery("select c from Cidade c where c.estado =:estado",Cidade.class);
queryCidades.setParameter("estado", objetoEstado);
List<Cidade> cidades = queryCidades.getResultList();
```

espero que funcione.

Att